# CS connections to Life Science for ages 14-18?

Tags: secondary-education

What are activities that have been successfully used to integrate student learning across life science and computer science for ages 14-18? (Note [related question for ages 11-14](https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/questions/1262/cs-conncetions-to-life-sciences-for-ages-11-14).) The question seeks classroom-tested activities which:

- Reinforce or **teach computer science** age-appropriate knowledge, skills, concepts, and practices
- Reinforce or **teach life science** age-appropriate knowledge, skills, concepts, or practices
- Demonstrate the **interdisciplinary impact** of computer science in the life sciences
- **Engage** students with active learning